# VBA matching 0 with scientific notation close to zero

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, rounding

I am trying to match values between arrays.

I realize some operations are calculating these as False when if should be true. One of the values it seems contains more decimal values.

```
        Debug.Print x / 100
        Debug.Print y
        Debug.Print (x / 100) - y
```

This results in:

0.9248

0.9248

1.11022302462516E-16

I've tried using round & formatcurrency. While it will show the values  as rounded, it still retains the scientific notation when calculating.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how i can get x = y to flag as 'true'?

Thanks.

Comment: You might consider reading [Is floating-point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thanks for link. I did not know what this problem was called to search for a solution. I ended up using abs() < 0.000001 as my tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Link by BigBen, used abs function and check if less then a specific value.